# Syntax error when trying to remove trailing zeros in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

To avoid cosmetic adjustments in the presentation layer, I need to remove trailing zeros from my data outputs - e.g. in my Hours column I need "2" as opposed to "2.000" or "18.5" as opposed to "18.500".

Having reviewed existing resources, I've come up with the following:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(U.START_TIME + INTERVAL 1 hour, '%H:%i') as Start
, DATE_FORMAT(U.END_TIME + INTERVAL 1 hour, '%H:%i') as End
, CAST(CAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, U.START_TIME, U.END_TIME)/60 as DECIMAL (6,2)) as FLOAT) as Hours
, REQUESTER_COMMENT as Requester_Commment
FROM VW_USER_SCHEDULE_INSTANCES U
```

I keep getting the error message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FLOAT), REQUESTER_COMMENT as Requester_Comment

I'm struggling to work out what needs to be adjusted to avoid the error. Trying to integrate float is preventing any outputs. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious - I'm a total SQL beginner. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should get into the habit of reading the documentation for functions like `CAST()`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

If you read the docs, you would learn that `CAST()` doesn't support FLOAT as a destination type. You can use BINARY, CHAR, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, JSON, NCHAR, SIGNED INTEGER, TIME or UNSIGNED INTEGER. But not FLOAT or DOUBLE.

I suggest you try the `ROUND()` function. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

But my preferred answer is that you should use SQL for fetching raw data, and do formatting for a given presentation in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `to_seconds()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(U.START_TIME + INTERVAL 1 hour, '%H:%i') as Start,
       DATE_FORMAT(U.END_TIME + INTERVAL 1 hour, '%H:%i') as End,
       (TO_SECONDS(U.END_TIME) - TO_SECONDS(U.START_TIME)) / (60*60) as Hours,
       REQUESTER_COMMENT as Requester_Commment
FROM VW_USER_SCHEDULE_INSTANCES U;
```

You can format it however you like.

Comment: Thank you for responding Gordon. Unfortunately this does not seem to resolve the problem as the output is the same as before when using TIMESTAMPDIFF. When trying to apply float to this as before, I still receive the same error message.